# Apps script to update timestamp in one cell on each tab in a google sheet upon any edit of that tab

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

I have a third party updating a google sheet for me and would like a simple script showing a timestamp in cell B1 of each tab of the script upon any edit of that tab.  So if Sheet1 was edited in any way, cell B1 of Sheet1 would update the timestamp.  Same with Sheet2.  I've got a script that works for Sheet2, but not for Sheet1.  If I delete the second function, it works for Sheet1.  I'm sure I'm doing this wrong and would appreciate any help.  Here's what I have now:

```
function onEdit() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B1").setValue(new Date());
}

function onEdit() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("B1").setValue(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of the fact that an onEdit will always require a manual edit in the spreadsheet?  Updates to the sheet by some third party app will not be considered as an edit, hence the timestamp will not be updated.

If you are manually editing the spreadsheet (sheets) you can try

```
function onEdit(e) {
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I could have been clearer with my use of third party.  I mean I've hired someone to update information on each of the sheets.  So in this case it is a manual edit, and it appears that your suggestion works beautifully.  Thank you for your time and expertise!

Answer (score 0):

A single Google Apps Script project can't have to `onEdit` functions due to how JavaScript works.

The following code example use if statements and the on edit event object to add the timestamp only to the sheet that was edited

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const name = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  if(name === 'Sheet1') e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B1").setValue(new Date());
  if(name === 'Sheet2') e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("B1").setValue(new Date());
}
```

Comment: I appreciate knowing that about more than one onEdit functions.  Your suggested script appears to be another good way of handing my problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ["Sheet1","Sheet2"];//Add the sheet names you wish it to work on
  if(~shts.indexOf(sh.getName())) {
    sh.getRange("B1").setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that you have your solution for timestamp. Posting here with another possible solution in case needed for different scenario

Some **background** for my case:

- I have multiple sheets in the spreadsheet to run and generate the
  timestamp
- I want to skip my first sheet without running to generate timestamp
  in it
- I want every edit, even if each value that I paste from Excel to
  generate timestamp
- I want the timestamp to be individual, each row have their own
  timestamp precise to every second
- I don't want a total refresh of the entire sheet timestamp when I am
  editing any other row
- I have a column that is a MUST FILL value to justify whether the
  timestamp needs to be generated for that particular row
- I want to specify my timestamp on a dedicated column only

```
function timestamp() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const totalSheet = ss.getSheets();

  for (let a=1; a<totalSheet.length; a++) {
    let sheet = ss.getSheets()[a];
    let range = sheet.getDataRange();
    let values = range.getValues(); 

    function autoCount() {
      let rowCount;
      for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        rowCount = i
        if (values[i][0] === '') {
          break;
        }
      }
      return rowCount
    }

    rowNum = autoCount()

    for(let j=1; j<rowNum+1; j++){
      if (sheet.getRange(j+1,7).getValue() === '') {
        sheet.getRange(j+1,7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

1. First, I made a `const totalSheet` with `getSheets()` and run it
   with a `for` loop. That is to identify the total number of sheets
   inside that spreadsheet. Take note, in here, I made `let a=1;`
   supposed all JavaScript the same, starts with `0`, value `1` is to
   **skip the first sheet** and run on the second sheet onwards
2. then, you will notice a function `let sheet = ss.getSheets()[a]`
   inside the loop. Take note, it is not supposed to use `const` if
   your value inside the **variable is constantly changing**, so use
   `let` instead will work fine.
3. then, you will see a `function autoCount()`. That is to make a `for`
   loop to count the number of rows that have values edited in it. The
   `if (values[i][0] === '')` is to navigate the script to search
   through the entire sheet that has value, looking at the row `i` and
   the column `0`. Here, the `0` is indicating the **first column** of the
   sheet, and the `i` is the row of the sheet. Yes, it works like a
   `json` object with `panda` feeling.
4. then, you found the number of rows that are edited by running the
   `autoCount()`. Give it a `rowNum` variable to contain the result.
5. then, pass that `rowNum` into a new `for` loop, and use `if (sheeet.getRange(j+1,7).getValue() === '')` to determine which row
   has not been edited with timestamp. Take note, where the `7` here
   indicating the **7th column** of the sheet is the place that I want a
   timestamp.
6. inside the `for` loop, is to `setValue` with date in a specified
   format of `("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`. You are free to edit into any
   style you like
7. ohya, do remember to deploy to activate the trigger with event type
   as `On Change`. That is not limiting to edit, but for all kinds of
   changes **including paste**.

Here's a screenshot on how it would look like:

[image: First Column Value 7th Column Timestamp]

Lastly, please take note on some of my backgrounds before deciding to or not to have the solution to work for your case. Cheers, and happy coding~!